# Unable to get attributes back from GetCustomAttributes

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, reflection

In my MiddleTier project in a solution I have Customer classes, one of them defined with Attribute1

```
public class Customer2
{
    public string Name2 { get; set; }

    public int Age2 { get; set; }
}

[MyAttribute1]
public class Customer1
{
    [MyAttribute1(DefaultValue = "Must Enter Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [MyAttribute1(DefaultValue = "Must Enter Age")]
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All)]
public class MyAttribute1 : Attribute
{
    public string DefaultValue { get; set; }

}
```

In a separate project, I reference MiddleTier DLL and I want to enumerate through all the classes in this DLL and identify Customer1 class that is associated with Attribute1.

```
            Assembly assembly =  Assembly.LoadFrom(@"C:\myfolder\MiddleTier\bin\Debug\MiddleTier.dll");

            foreach (Type type in assembly.GetTypes())
            {

                var attribs = type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyAttribute1), false); <--- problem
                if (attribs != null && attribs.Length > 0)
                {
....
                }
            }
```

I am **not getting any attributes back by the GetCustomAttributes** call. What am I doing wrong? please help. Thanks

Comment: I'm guessing that perhaps somehow the runtime considers the `MyAttribute1` type compiled for MiddleTier.dll is different than the `MyAttribute1` type loaded at runtime for the current domain.

Comment: Can you try calling the non-typed overload `GetCustomAttributes(false)` and then do a check on the type of the entry.  Like `if (attribs.Length > 0) { Console.WriteLine(attribs[0].GetType() == typeof(MyAttribute1)); }`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that you are actually loading the assembly twice and doing so from two different locations. This results in the assemblies being loaded into two different contexts, which, in turn, results in your types being incompatible. You can easily verify this when you try to run this code (of course, you will need to change the path to the assembly):

```
foreach (Type type in Assembly.LoadFrom(@"C:\ClassLibrary1.dll").GetTypes())
{
     MyAttribute1 attribute = type.GetCustomAttributes(false)
                                  .Cast<MyAttribute1>()
                                  .SingleOrDefault();
    if (attribute != null)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(type.Name);
    }

}
```

That will result in following exception being thrown:

> [A]ClassLibrary1.MyAttribute1 cannot be cast to
>   [B]ClassLibrary1.MyAttribute1. Type A originates from 'ClassLibrary1,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' in the context
>   'LoadFrom' at location 'C:\ClassLibrary1.dll'. Type B originates from
>   'ClassLibrary1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
>   in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\Users\Nikola\Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2010\Projects\ConsoleApplication12\ConsoleApplication12\bin\Debug\ClassLibrary1.dll'.

**So, how to solve it?**

You simply need to load the assembly by using `Assembly.Load("ClassLibrary1")`. That will make sure that you are working within the single context and your original code will work.

Check out [this blogpost](http://geekswithblogs.net/rupreet/archive/2010/02/16/137988.aspx) which treats upon exactly the same issue you are having. It also may be helpful to read something about [load contexts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd153782.aspx).

Comment: I had the case where somebody had linked source file in another project, and I had reference to these two assemblies (with the same source file) and Attributes defined in the source file did not work.

Answer (score -2):

`var attribs = (MyAttribute1)type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyAttribute1), false)[someIndex];`

Comment: Right, you need to cast it as your attribute type.

Comment: Actually, this returns an object array of the type so you need to cast it as `MyAttribute1[]`.

Comment: Actually, I don't think this solves the problem.  dotnet-practitioner isn't getting any results.  Without the casting you would still receive a non-null object array with length > 0.

Comment: -1. I agree with Chris, this does not solve the problem at all.